# Using a list to select the same position in multiple arrays in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have 53 two-dimensional numpy arrays of equivalent size. My first array has values of zeroes and ones (with a few unimportant -1 (NaN values). I'm trying to use the values of the first array to select values in the remaining to make individual tuple/one-dimensional array/vector that contains 52 elements in order. I'd like to make a random 100 of these vectors that keep the dataset ratios in the first array. So I'd have to be able to put them into separate datasets that can be shuffled before selection.

To achieve this I figured it was important to create a list of elements in the first array and their location. Code to follow.

```
np.unique(index, return_counts = True)

# -1, 25. 0, 1210816. 1 , 1210816
###

wpx = 1916546
nwpx = 1210816
tpx = wpx + nwpx
wpxp = wpx/tpx * 100 #61%
nwpxp = nwpx/tpx * 100 #39%
#tpx
#wpxp
#nwpxp

###
#create a list of all values and their locations
#write values into txt/csv for portability to other projects using same data
indexdict = {}
i=0
j=0
indexfile = open('/location1/location2/file1.txt','w')
for ivalue in index:
#    while j < 5:
    while j < len(ivalue):
        #indexdict[(i,j)]=ivalue[j]
        indexfile.write("%i,%i,%i\n"%(i,j,ivalue[j]))
        j+=1
    j=0
    i+=1
#print(indexdict)
indexfile.close()
```

This generates a text (CSV) file that contains data that looks like this (X, Y, Value)

```
643,1613,1
643,1614,1
643,1615,1
643,1616,1
643,1617,0
643,1618,0
643,1619,0
```

I then separate the values into something that can be shuffled.

```
###
#Read text in and sort values into separate "buckets"
indexfile = open('/location1/location2/file1.txt','r')
zerointerest=[]
TargetA=[]
TargetB=[]
for line in indexfile:
    line=line.rstrip()
    iline=line.split(',')
    #print(iline[2])
    if iline[2] == "-1":
        zerointerest.append((iline[0],iline[1]))
    elif iline[2] == "0":
        TargetA.append((iline[0],iline[1]))
    elif iline[2] == "1":
        TargetB.append((iline[0],iline[1]))  
indexfile.close()
#print(zerointerest)
#print(TargetA)
#print(TargetB)
```

This is where I get stuck. I've created a list of values and locations but I have no idea how to proceed. I cannot figure out how to use list I've created to select values at the same location in arrays 1- 52 before adding the value of array 53 to the end of it, IE:

```
[25,26,27,28,29,33,35,37,40,45,50,55,60,75,80,90,100,110,105,100,95,90,85,80,100,120,140,150,150,150,150,150,150,150,150,150,150,145,140,135,130,125,120,115,110,100,100,100,100,100,100,1]
```

Comment: I will be helpful both for you and people here if you could simplifyy the code provided to a [mcve], you could generated example arrays with random data for example in order to reproduce the problem, so we can test and give the adapted answer

Comment: You'll have to excuse me, I'm not quite versed at python yet. I can't fathom how to make my code minimal (I was under the impression that it already was). I'm also not sure of how to generate example arrays without sharing my datasets.

Comment: you could also use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to "Generates a random sample from a given 1-D array"  and [`numpy.random.shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html#numpy.random.shuffle) for "Modify a sequence in-place by shuffling its contents."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is some code for inspiration:

```
import numpy as np

a_list_of_2D_arrays = [ np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3) for _ in range(5) ]

# Create a uniaue 3D array by concatenating the arrays:
a_3D_array = np.dstack(a_list_of_2D_arrays)

print(a_3D_array.shape)  # (3, 3, 5)

mask = np.array([[0, 0, 1],   # your first array?
                 [-1, 0, 1],
                 [1, 0, -1]])

mask.nonzero() # a tuple of indexes:
# gives (array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2]), array([2, 0, 2, 0, 2]))

(mask == 1).nonzero()  # consider only the 1 values
# gives (array([0, 1, 2]), array([2, 2, 0]))

a_3D_array[mask.nonzero()]  # extract the values along the third dim
                            # at the given indexes
```

the last line gives:

```
array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [8, 8, 8, 8, 8]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I conceptualised making a 3 dimensional (stack) array and this is super helpful for when I decide to work with much smaller parts of my data (massive amounts of thanks for that). I cannot use it in a major way however since my arrays are absolutely massive and memory quickly becomes an issue.